# Force magnitude and direction to maintain constant speed on given trajectory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

In circular motion to maintain a constant speed on a fixed circular path the force required has magnitude mv^2/r and is directed toward the centre of the circle.

How would this magnitude and direction of force be predicted for an arbitrary path. For example a mass m is moving along the negative x axis in Cartesian space towards the positive x axis and at the time where the mass reaches the origin a force acts on the mass such that the path the mass follows is of the form  y = x^2 what magnitude and direction of force is required to maintain a constant speed along such path?

Answer (score 0):

If the speed of the object is constant then the direction of the force acting on it must be at right angles to its trajectory at each point. The magnitude of the force is determined by the [radius of curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature) of its trajectory at each point.